# Display image in collection view by button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I want to display random image from array in my `UICollectionView`. I work with xib, and already create custom cell with image view. I want that when I click my button the image displaying in collection view, but don't know how to do this. I have 2 array in tempArr I initialize images, and in arrayForImages I insert image when button press.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)randomButton:(id)sender {
    NSInteger randIndex =  arc4random() % [tempArr count];
    NSInteger ind = arrayForImages.count;
    [arrayForImages insertObject:tempArr[randIndex] atIndex:ind];
    NSLog(@"array for index %@", arrayForImages);

}
```

Here is the Collection

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return arrayForImages.count;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

- (CustomCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageViewCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayForImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Delegates will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306613/pass-data-from-a-button-in-reused-custom-cell/39307083#39307083

Comment: reload the collection view. [your collection view relaod];  in Button click.

Comment: @saravanar it helps thank you!